# discrete math basic question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Al has 75 days to master discrete mathematics. He decides to study at least one
hour every day, but no more than a total of 125 hours. Assume Al always studies
in one hour units. Show there must be a sequence of consecutive days during which
he studies exactly 24 hours.

Comment: I think I'm missing something... couldn't Al just study one hour a day for 75 days?

Comment: Well a starting point is at least one hour a day produces 75 hours (is this enough to learn discrete maths?) or two hours a day is over shooting by 25 hours. So the question is can you learn discrete maths in less than 125 hours? It seem under defined from that point?

Comment: i dont know what it can imply....this is how i saw this question... some pigenhole concepts are applied somewhere... this is a bit complex to me..

Comment: The question as written doesn't make sense, since he can study 23 hours on the first day, 23 hours on the second day, 7 hours the third day, and one hour each other day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_k$ be the number of hours of work Al has done after $k$ days.  Then $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_{75}\}$ is an increasing sequence of distinct positive integers since Al does at least one hour of work each day.  Observe that $1 \leq a_k \leq 125$ since Al does at most $125$ hours of work over the $75$ days.

Let $b_k = a_k + 24$.  Then the sequence $\{b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots, b_{75}\}$ is also an increasing sequence of distinct positive integers.  Observe that $1 + 24 = 25 \leq b_k \leq 149 = 125 + 24$.

Now consider the union of the two sequences.  It consists of $150$ numbers that are at least $1$ and at most $149$.  Thus, two of them must be the same.  Hence, $b_k = a_k + 24 = a_j$ for some $j, k$.  Thus, $a_j - a_k = 24$, so Al does exactly $24$ hours of work from day $a_{k + 1}$ to day $a_j$.

This is a clever application of the Pigeonhole Principle that forced me to consult my combinatorics notes.

Comment: that was so definitive and clear...Thanks for a kind help

Comment: You're welcome.